# Adjusting image size

Tags: lightning-web-components, images, size

I want to fix size of any image in lightning web component , I used this code but when the image is small the image take just her size that work just if the image is to large .

How can I fixe this .

```
<div style="max-width:82%;">
   <img style="max-width:80%;max-height:80%;" src ={image} > 
</div>
```

Comment: Consider using "width" and "height" if you want small images enlarged and large images shrunk. However, note that small images may look bad if enlarged too much due to pixilation. This will also potentially distort images (lose aspect ratio).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using  using "width" and "height"  so my code is

```html
<div style="max-width:95%;">
  <img style="max-width:85%;max-height:90%; height: 220px; width: 480px;" src={image}> 
</div>
```

Comment: Note my comments on your question.

Comment: @PhilW How can I do this please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio